# Apply function over values whose keys match in another array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form.value as below

```
 form.value = {
  "to_date": "2019-03-21T05:00:00.000Z",
  "from_date": "2019-03-13T05:00:00.000Z",
  "is_form": ""
  "errors":""
}
```

I have an array as below

```
filterArray = [
  "from_date",
  "to_date"
]
```

I want to iterate over the form.value object keys and apply a function ( `converFormat()`)  over the value of the keys that match in the filter array
as shown below

```
  form.value = {
  "to_date": "2019-03-21T05:00:00.000Z",       // apply a function() over value since key is present in the filterArray
  "from_date": "2019-03-13T05:00:00.000Z",     // apply a function() over value since key is present in the filterArray
  "is_form": ""                               
  "errors":""                                  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Object.keys(form.value).filter(key => filterArray.includes(key)).forEach(key => {
  form.value[key] = myFunction(form.value[key])
})

// Or if you want to cache the value in some other variable

const customFormValue = {
  ...form.value,
  ...Object.keys(form.value)
    .filter(key => filterArray.includes(key))
    .reduce(
      (pr, curr) => ({
        ...pr,
        [curr]: myFunction(form.value[curr])
      }),
      {}
    )
};
```